# Why I only see Read Me file for Git hub pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, deployment, github-pages

I deployed my react app to Git hub and was trying to create GitHub pages URL.
I followed all the steps from here: https://medium.com/@isharamalaviarachchi/how-to-deploy-your-react-app-into-github-pages-b2c96292b18e

Made sure Sourse set to Master from root folder and created scripts:

```
 "predeploy": "npm run build",
  "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
```

And run npm run deploy:

See pic attached:

[image]

I have tried running npm run deploy and getting a message that it already exists.
I tried deleting the build folder and run npm run build again for no avail
Again my root folder on GitHub is set to Root, and this is a React project

Comment: This is a link to my Git hub:https://github.com/BernaraD/glx

Comment: Did you run `npm run deploy`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change branch to gh-pages on settings